# Forcing download of static files in MEDIA_URL with Django and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I can reach (and view) static uploaded files at the url `/site_media/*`.

But how can I force download of every static file under `site_media` using mod_wsgi?

Comment: so what you want is to have the static files served via mod_wsgi rather than just plain apache?